# Equal height columns with no background

Tags: html, css, xhtml, layout

Here is an example code http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/kmGATPRovx. How can I make the second block looks like the first one with more content in .front-content block? The most problem is the position of .front-description's bottom border.

Comment: A live example would be much better and appreciated, help us to help you :)

Comment: You could click "Download" and save it as a HTML file ;)

Comment: By the way, for something as simple as two horizontally-stacked columns, you could also consider using `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;` as it keeps the blocks 'in layout' and avoids clearing problems.

Comment: here is a live example http://paste.ideaslabs.com/download/kmGATPRovx

Comment: @Molfar - that is not a live example, that is your code. A live example is where we can see how that code behaves.

Comment: @Delan Azabani: inline-block doesn't seem to work well with all browsers. For example in IE8 in some modes it chooses to use for sometimes seemingly random reasons. In some cases div with display attribute inline-block works just fine when replaced with span element with span's default display attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion for a "solution" can be found [here](http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/6xdwcehv0y). It's not elegant, but in the browser (IE/FF quick test) it looks like what I think you were looking for. What I did was add a new div.front-wrapper with desired border-bottom and width of 25% and a negative margin-top. I removed the border-bottom from div.front-description. Then I placed an empty div with the class front-wrapper after the "wrapping" -div  is closed.

The front-wrapper of course now has a misleading class name as it's not wrapping anything, but that's what I started to use it for, but couldn't get it working as desired. So do rename it.